# Lip-Sync issues: how can this be solved?

Tags: synchronization

We know that **audio-video** data in most containers/files are two separate streams of data. This leads to the infamous **lip-sync** issue during transmission (e.g. network) or playback.

I am not an expert but I dare to ask. How do we solve this?

From a programming perspective, the solution has been to *re-encode* audio and video length to match if there was an error that caused the mismatch to begin with.

My hypothetical solution would be to have both audio and video data on one stream. Of course this is impossible but I know that this problem will surely be solved one day.

Please don’t hesitate! Your idea might give someone in the future [or now] a brilliant solution.